# Crear array de objetos a partir de arrays dinamicos en Javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando guardar un array de objetos que se creen dinamicamente apartir de arrays, lo explico con lo siguiente.

Tengo un array principal que será la key de los objetos, el siguiente:

```
var header = ['start_date', 'final_date', 'value']
```

**NOTA**: la variable header no es estatica estará cambiando, es decir no será siempre los mismos valores pueden cambiar y que no sean start_date, final_date y value sino sean otros. Al igual con el array data que contendrá otros array, estos también pueden cambiar. Por eso la aclaración de dinamicos en el titulo

Y a medida en que se vam generando los array serán de la siguiente manera:

```
    var data = [
     ['12-12-2021', '31-12-2021', '45']
     ['09-06-2022', '30-07-2023', '78']
     ['17-08-2022', '29-09-2023', '57']
    ]
```

Por más que he intentado usando varias métodos no logro sacar el siguiente resultado.

```
    var finalData = [
     {start_date: 12-12-2021, final_date: 31-12-2021, value: 45}
     {start_date: 09-06-2022, final_date: 30-07-2023, value: 78}
     {start_date: 17-08-2022, final_date: 29-09-2023, value: 57}
    ]
```

Agradezco cualquier ayuda para poderlo resolver.

Una de las maneras que intente fue la siguiente:

```
var headerObj = Object.assign({}, header);
var arrayObj = [];
 for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  arrayObj.push(Object.assign({}, data[i]));
}

finalData = arrayObj.map(element => {
  return = {
   [headerObj] : element
  }
});
```

Comment: Considera incluir lo que has intentado. Independiente que no te funcione, nos da más contexto de lo que trataste hacer y donde falla.

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario, ya agregue una forma en que intenté hacerlo. (Hice varias formas, pero las iba borrando cuando no funcionaban)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La forma más simple es crear un nuevo objeto y acceder mediane el indice tanto a la posición del objeto con el nombre de la clave como al respectivo valor.

Esto asumiendo que siempre el tamaño del arreglo con los nombres de las cabeceras y los valores tienen el mismo largo. De igual forma, asumiendo que siempre el orden de las cabeceras está ad hoc con la posición de los datos.

Las suposiciones anteriores están basadas en el resultado esperado.

```js
var headers = ['start_date', 'final_date', 'value']
var data = [
     ['12-12-2021', '31-12-2021', '45'],
     ['09-06-2022', '30-07-2023', '78'],
     ['17-08-2022', '29-09-2023', '57']
 ]
 
 
function pushHeadersToData(data, headers){
  let formated = [] 
  data.forEach((element, index) => {
    let withKeys = {}
    for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
      withKeys[headers[i]] = element[i]
    }
    formated.push(withKeys)
  })
  return formated
}


let data_formated = pushHeadersToData(data, headers)
console.log(data_formated)
```

PD: He dejado el código en una función para que lo puedas reutilizar en caso que los tamaños cambien en ejecución. Solo seria cosa de volver a llamar a la función y pasarle los valores actualizados.